# Using PaperTrail in Rails to approve/deny edits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

Here is my code so far:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_paper_trail meta: { athlete_id: :athlete_id, approved: false },
                  if: Proc.new { |v| v.needs_approval? }
  validate :should_be_saved?

  def should_be_saved?
    errors.add(:base, 'added for approval') if needs_approval?
  end

  def needs_approval
    @needs_approval ||= false
  end

  def needs_approval?
    @needs_approval
  end

end

# ApplicationController
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def user_for_paper_trail
    return unless user_signed_in?
    original_user.present? ? original_user : current_user
  end

  # Used to determine the contributor
  # When contributor logs in, warden saves the contributor_id in session
  def original_user
    return nil unless remember_contributor_id?
    @original_user ||= User.find(remember_contributor_id)
  end

  def info_for_paper_trail
    { athlete_id: current_user.id } if current_user
  end

end
```

The problem I am running into currently is when the Video object is saved the validation fails (because I told it too), but I need for the validation to fail but the version object continue with its creation. Just not too sure how to go about doing that.

**EDITS**
Here is my code (the code below is still using the `ApplicationController` code from above):

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  # .. other methods

  include Contributable
  attr_accessible :video_type_id, :athlete_id, :uploader_id, :created_at, :updated_at, :uniform_number, :featured,
                  :name, :panda_id, :date, :thumbnail_url, :mp4_video_url, :from_mobile_device, :duration, :sport_id,
                  :delted_at, :approved
end

module Contributable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_paper_trail meta: { athlete_id: :athlete_id, approved: false },
                    unless: Proc.new { |obj| obj.approved? },
                    skip: [:approved]
  end

  def log_changes_or_update(params, contributor = nil)
    update_attribute(:approved, false) unless contributor.blank?

    if contributor.blank?
      update_attributes params
    else
      self.attributes = params
      self.send(:record_update)
      self.versions.map(&:save)
    end
  end

end

class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def update
    # ... other code
    # original_user is the contributor currently logged in
    @video.log_changes_or_update(params[:video], original_user)
  end
end
```

The app I am working on has a small layer of complexity that allows for users with a certain role to edit profiles they have access too. I am trying to save the versions of each change out (using `paper_trail`) without affecting the existing object.

The code above works exactly how I want it to, however, I am just curious to know if in my `log_changes_or_update` method is not the correct way to go about accomplishing the overall goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just remove the validation and add an `approved` attribute with a default value of `false` to the `Video` model?  That way the `Video` object is saved and a paper_trail `version` is created.  Later when the video gets approved paper_trail will note that change too.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is exactly what I wound up doing! Thanks!

Comment: I updated my question to include some new code I was working with. Thoughts?

Comment: Hmmm... that might be a better fit for a new question either here or on codereview.stackexchange.com.  On first look the new code is non-obvious.